# How to interact with shadow-root DOM element in Chrome with VBA

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dom, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to interact element in this page but I can't, I figured out it happened because #shadow-root.

But, I still don't know how to interact with these thing.

Also, I would like to know the way to make its work with VBA

This is the link for example : https://books-pwakit.appspot.com/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
element=driver.ExecuteScript(
    "return document.querySelector('csslocator').shadowRoot.querySelector('csslocator')")
```

you have to find the root element that has the shadoow root and then call shadowRoot on it and then call querySelector again to find specfic element inside it

This is because shadowdom is not part of DOM

Comment: Thanks a lot, I finally found an answer by your advise and now I learned to find the correct path in console.
Also, the correct for selenium should be 
Set element = d.ExecuteScript("return document.querySelector('book-app').shadowRoot.querySelector('app-header > app-toolbar.toolbar-bottom').querySelector('book-input-decorator').querySelector('input')")